# Unbind event by name on element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element with two class that trigger two click events.

Now I want to unbind one of the events of the element, but I dont know which click event it´s related with the class that define the event

Here my code:

Here the "a" element

```
    <a id="addTechnicalCriteriaButton${parcel.id}" href="javascript:void(0);"
   class="col-xs-2 glossary-content addTechnicalCriteriaButton${parcel.id} addTechnicalCriteriaLink openDialog" data-parcel-id="${parcel.id}">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></i> <spring:message code="label.add"/>
</a>
```

Here my js

```
         var openingDialogEvent = function () {
    $(".openDialog").on("click.modalDialog", function () {
        loadingOpeningDialog = true;
        currentElement = $(this);
        loadClickEvents();
        currentElement.off();
    });
};
```

in another js

```
       $('.addTechnicalCriteriaLink').click(function () {
          if (loadingCriteriaDialog === false) {
               loadingCriteriaDialog = true;
                    $.when(addTechnicalCriteria($(this).data('parcel-id'))).then(function () {
                            loadingCriteriaDialog = false;
                        }
                    );
                }
            });
```

Any idea?

Comment: Event handlers are not bound to _classes_. Event handlers are bound to _elements_.

Comment: @Satpal the code help you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing event handlers has nothing to do with the class used to add the handler(then handlers are attached to the dom element). You can use event namespacing to add/remove specific handlers like

```js
$('.c1').on('click.one', function() {
  snippet.log('c1 click');
});
$('.c2').on('click.two', function() {
  snippet.log('c2 click');
});

$('.one').click(function() {
  $('#c').off('click.one');
});
$('.two').click(function() {
  $('#c').off('click.two');
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="c" class="c1 c2">Test</button>
<button class="one">One</button>
<button class="two">Two</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/) to bind the event. then you can use [`.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/) to remove an event handler using *namespace*

```js
$(function() {
  $('.a').on('click.a', function() {
    alert('a clicked');
  });
  $('.b').on('click.b', function() {
    alert('b clicked');
  });

  $('div').off('click.a');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="a b">div</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use namespaces when attaching handlers using jQuery that we can later refer to. We do this by following the event name with a dot `.` and a unique name we want to reference later. `click.firstEvent`.

Doing this allows us to unbind later on in our code:

`$('#someElement').bind('click.firstEvent', function () { /* do stuff */ });`
`$('#someElement').bind('click.secondEvent', function () {/ * do other stuff */});`

Now we can unbind only the first event using the namespace we provided.

`$('#someElement').unbind('click.firstEvent');`